# ¿Cómo editar registros con react?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un formulario con el cual quiero editar registros pero actualmente no edita el registro en la base de datos solo en el front end.

el formulario es el siguiente:

```
<div className='card-panel'>
  <div className='col s12 m12 l12'>
    <div className= 'row'>
      <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
        <input value={this.props.item.descripcion} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "descripcion")} name="descripcion" type="text" className='validate'/>
      </div>

      <div className='col s12 m4 l4'>
        <label htmlFor='clienteint'>Cliente interno</label> 
        <select name='clienteint' value={this.props.item.idfin_cliente_interno} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "idfin_cliente_interno")} className='browser-default'>
          { this.state.getSearchIntclient.map((clienteint)=>
            <option key={clienteint.value} value={clienteint.value}>{clienteint.text}</option>)
          }
        </select>
      </div>

      <div className="row-in">
        <div className='input-field col s6'>
          <input  value={this.props.item.id_cliente } onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "id_cliente")} name="cliente" type="number" className='validate'></input>
          <span className="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Cliente</span>
        </div>

        <div className="row">
          <ul >
            <li><a data-target="modal1" className="btn-floating modal-trigger" href="#modal1"><i className="material-icons">search</i></a></li>
          </ul>
          <label htmlFor='cliente'>Busqueda</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4'>
        <input value={this.props.item.vigencia_inicio} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "vigencia_inicio")} name="vigencia_inicio" type="date" className='validate'/>
        <span className="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Vigencia inicial</span>
      </div>              

      <div className='input-field col s12 m4 l4' >
          <input value={this.props.item.vigencia_final} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "vigencia_final")} name="vigencia_final" type="date" className='validate'/>
          <span className="helper-text" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Vigencia final</span>
      </div>                        

      <div >
        <div className='col s12 m10 l10'>
            <button onClick={this.handlerUpdate} type='submit' className="btn waves-effect waves-light" data-position="bottom" ><i className="material-icons right">mode_edit</i>Edit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>           
</div>
```

y busco editar los registros con la siguiente función:

```
handlerUpdate() {
    const _data = Object.assign({}, this.state);
    _data['fecha_ultima_modificacion'] = Date.now();
    _data['usuario_ultima_modificacion']=localStorage.getItem("username");
    delete _data['fecha_creacion'];
    delete _data['usuario_creacion'] ;
    delete _data['id_booking_hash'] ;
    delete _data['estado'];
    delete _data['descripcion'];
    delete _data['id_cliente'];
    return CleverRequest.put(CleverConfig.getApiUrl('booking') + '/bookingconfig/put/'+ this.props.item.idbooking_be_config, _data, (response, error) => {
        if (!error) {
            if(!response){
                Materialize.toast('Edited Item', 4000);
            }
        } else {
            Materialize.toast('Something went wrong, please try again.', 4000);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

El problema es que solo me edita el registro en el front end, mientras que en la base de datos no muestra el cambio en el registro.
Solo me muestra un 204 y no se cual es el error.
Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos y muchas gracias